# Is it possible to make integer math with C preprocessor?

Tags: c-preprocessor

Is it possible to make integer math with C preprocessor(`cpp`)? For example subtract one defined value from another and as a result `cpp` prints out the subtraction result.

Comment: boost preprocessor provides that something similar for c++. even though boost is a c++ library, you can still use their source code and documentation as reference and inspiration. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by "prints out the subtraction result"?I.e. what do you want to achieve in the end? Also I believe you do not mean C++ program by "cpp"; because that would of course be able to print the difference of any two numbers, including two numbers which are represented by pre-processor macros.